# Bigquery: Displaying dataset loocation while listing datasets with bq command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bq

How to show `data-location` while doing `dataset` listing with `bq` command.

e.g `bq ls` will show `datasetId` . I want the dataset `location` information like along with below output.

```
$ bq ls
    datasetId
-----------------------
 my_test_data
 my_sample_data
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply run

```
bq ls --format=json
```

Then each entry will contain the dataset id and the location of the dataset.
You may want to use prettyjson for a better view:

```
bq ls --format=prettyjson
```